# R: Remove Rows From Data Frame [i] of List 1 based on Index values from Data Frame [j] of List 2

Tags: r, list, function, iteration

I have the following problem:

I have one list of data frames that includes a heart rate signal for each participant. Furthermore, I have a list of data frames which include the index values of outliers, which I want to remove. What I want to do is to write a function, which removes outliers from the HR signal of participant 1 in List 1 based on Index values from outlier index values of participant 1 in List 2, and get an output list of cleaned HR signal without the indexed outliers. In other words, I want to remove rows in Element[i] in List 1 based on the index values of Element[i] in list 2.

Example Code and Description:

```
HR = list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5) # list of data frames each containing one heart rate signal
outlier_list = list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5) # list of data frames each cointaining the index values of the corresponding particiapant, which I want to remove --> e.g. HR$df1 & outlier_list$df1 contain values for participant 1

# I tried the following:
    HR_clean = lapply(HR, function(x){ lapply(outlier_list, function(i){
    x[-c(i)]})
})
```

Unfortunately the HR_clean output does not yield any useful result.

I hope it is clear what I am trying to achieve.
I am grateful for any tips!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, it should not be a nested loop.  Instead, this should be done on corresponding elements and it is easier with `Map`

```
Map(function(dat, i) dat[-i], HR, outlier_list)
```